# "Filter" or "Map" the same array using different tests without looping multiple times?

Tags: javascript

For example I have

```
var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
```

Is there a way to write this:

```
var multiplesOf2 = nums.filter(...)
var multiplesOf3 = nums.filter(...)
var greaterThan7 = nums.filter(...)
```

And have it be as efficient as

```
var multiplesOf2 = [], multiplesOf3 = [], greaterThan7  = [];
nums.forEach(function (num) {
  if (...) { multiplesOf2.push(num); }
  if (...) { multiplesOf3.push(num); }
  if (...) { greatherThan7.push(num); }
})
```

?

Comment: [There are some libraries which "lazily" evaluate such chains](http://danieltao.com/lazy.js/). But there is no built-in solution.

Comment: What's the goal? Your `.forEach()` successfully does what your title asks.

Comment: Skim through http://interglacial.com/hoj/hoj.html#1.8.2:_Partitioning It's a JavaScript translation of some of the code from the book **Higher Order Perl**, and shows some other ways to handle partitioning.  Perl has List::MoreUtils::part, which does what you're after.  Too bad there's not a common library for JS that has this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var LazyArray = defclass({
    constructor: function (xs) {
        this.xs = xs;
        this.fs = [];
    },
    iterate: function () {
        var xs = this.xs, m = xs.length;
        var fs = this.fs, n = fs.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            var x =  xs[i];

            for (var j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                var f = fs[j], p = f(x, i, xs);
                if (p) fs.splice(j--, 1), n--;  // break out of the loop
            }
        }

        fs.length = 0;
    },
    filter: function (f) {
        var ys = [];

        this.fs.push(function (x) {
            if (f(x)) ys.push(x);
        });

        return ys;
    }
});
```

Here's how you would use it:

```
var nums = new LazyArray([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);

var multiplesOf2 = nums.filter(...);
var multiplesOf3 = nums.filter(...);
var greaterThan7 = nums.filter(...);

nums.iterate();
```

Note however that performance-wise there's no real benefit. If the input array has `m` items and there are `n` calls to `filter` then:

1. Traditionally you would loop through `m` items `n` times.
2. In this case you're looping through `n` iterators `m` times.

In either case the time complexity is `O(m * n)`. There's no real benefit of lazy evaluation unless you get to skip a few computations which you would otherwise unnecessarily have to do using strict evaluation.

P.S. You can extend the `LazyArray` class with functions for `map`, `reduce`, etc. just as easily.

---

**Edit:** I forgot the definition of `defclass`:

```
function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}
```

That's all folks.

Answer (score 1):

I can only guess that you want the `.forEach()` to be a little cleaner. You can use `.reduce()` if you think it helps.

```
var res = nums.reduce(function (obj, num) {
  if (...) { obj[2].push(num); }
  if (...) { obj[3].push(num); }
  if (...) { obj[7].push(num); }
  return obj;
}, {2:[],3:[],7:[]});
```

---

In ECMAScript 6, you'll be able to assign results to individual variables using destructuring assignment.

```
let {2:two, 3:three, 7:seven} = nums.reduce(function (obj, num) {
  if (...) { obj[2].push(num); }
  if (...) { obj[3].push(num); }
  if (...) { obj[7].push(num); }
  return obj;
}, {2:[],3:[],7:[]});
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to test the performance, but perhaps something like this will work if you want to pass in *functions*

```
function filters(list /* test, test, test*/) {
    var i, j, arr = [], tests;
    tests = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    j = tests.length;
    for (i = 0; i < j; ++i) arr[i] = [];
    list.forEach(function (element, index, array) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < j; ++i) 
            if (tests[i](element, index, array))
                arr[i].push(element);
    });
    return arr;
}

filters(
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], // first arg the Array
    function (e) {return 0 === e % 2;}, // any number of tests to filter
    function (e) {return 0 === e % 3;},
    function (e) {return e > 7;}
);
/*
[
    [2, 4, 6, 8],
    [3, 6, 9],
    [8, 9]
]
*/
```